# Behaviorsubject and of() behave ina completely different way

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular9, behaviorsubject

I am trying to reate a processing chain of observables where the first step must be a subject (I need to call .next() ). Using of() works, but returns an Observable, using a BehaviorSubject should have similar effects, yet it does not work: the observable created with of perfectly works and the subscription brings the data through the pipes and returns the modified data, while with the behaviorsubject the data stays in the subject and the subscription never gets data.

Example:

```
getProcessed(processed: string = null, identifier = 'default'): Observable<any> {
  const bs = new BehaviorSubject(this.start.data);
  this.localFilterSub.set(identifier, bs);
  this.localFilterObs.set(identifier, bs.asObservable());
  this.localFilterSet.set(identifier, {});
  this.process(processed, identifier);
  return this.localFilterObs.get(identifier);
}

process(name: string, identifier = 'default') {
  this.localFilterObs.set(identifier, this.doProcess(name, identifier));
}


private doProcess(name: string, identifier = 'default'): Observable<any>|Subject<any> {
  if (name) {
    const inst = new Op();

    const obss = [];
    obss.push(this.localFilterObs.get(identifier));
    obss.push(inst.getExternal());

    return forkJoin(obss).pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        console.log(name, data);
      }),
      map((data) => {
        return inst?.run(data);
        // this.done.push(name);
      }),
      tap((data) => {
        console.log(name, data);
      }),
    );
  } 
}
```

I really do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What does "yet it does not work" mean?  What is not working?  What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?  A `BehaviorSubject` won't behave exactly the same way as an observable you created with `of` does.

Comment: why? an observable created with of would be an observable having the given set of data, a behaviorsubject would be a subject (which is an observable) that emits the data as soon it is subscribed to. why should there be a difference?

Comment: i edited the question, in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forkJoin does not emit until all the observables complete. of will complete straight away but the behavior subject will not complete until you call complete. Use combineLatest and it will emit once all the observables have emitted.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject, of, forkJoin } = rxjs;

const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject('bs');

o$ = of('of')

forkJoin([bs$, o$]).subscribe(res => { console.log(res); });

console.log('Nothing yet as bs$ not complete');

setTimeout(() => { bs$.complete(); }, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

but combineLatest will emit straight away

```js
const { BehaviorSubject, of, combineLatest } = rxjs;

const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject('bs');

o$ = of('of')

combineLatest([bs$, o$]).subscribe(res => { console.log(res); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```